# What is the name of the alert that pops up on HTML forms alerting something is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, input

I am working on a static website and have some basic math being done via Javascript. I would like to alert the user that something is wrong via the little boxes next to a form input. Do you know the name of this alert and if it can be modified?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change these with the JavaScript method `setCustomValidity`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#validating_forms_using_javascript